# C# EWS Change the MapiPropertyType of an extended property

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi

I would like to know if i change the data type for an EWS Extended Property if there is anything i need to do akin to altering the table in a DB before using it?

Currently i just declare a custom extended property and start using it, but now i want to change it from `MapiPropertyType.Integer` to `MapiPropertyType.Long`.

The following is an example property definition like my current one:
`static class MyAppSchema {
   private static readonly Guid property_set = Guid.Parse("{my guid value}");
   public static ExtendedPropertyDefinition ItemId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
       propertySetId: property_set,
       name: "ItemId",
       mapiType: MapiPropertyType.Integer
   );
}`

i currently use it like this:

- `item.SetProperty<int>(MyAppSchema.ItemId, item_from_another_db.ItemId);`

I would like to start using the following property definition instead:
`static class MyAppSchema {
   private static readonly Guid property_set = Guid.Parse("{my guid value}");
   public static ExtendedPropertyDefinition ItemId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
       propertySetId: property_set,
       name: "ItemId",
       mapiType: MapiPropertyType.Long
   );
}`

i'd start using it like this:

- `item.SetProperty<long>(MyAppSchema.ItemId, item_from_another_db.ItemId);`

There is existing data in the mailboxes concerned and i would still like to be able to use search filters like `SearchFilter.IsEqualTo`.  I'm concerned that if i change the data type i'll be setting myself up for problems later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do that - once you used a custom property in a particular mailbox, you are stuck with that property and its definition forever. You'd need to create a property with a different name if you want a different type.

Comment: bugger i was hoping you wouldn't say that.  Do you know if there is supporting documentation? because i could only find how to create, set and get, or are we assuming by the lack of documentation that its not possible?

Comment: That is treated as given, especially in MAPI. Even in a regular SQL database, you need  to convert all existing data to the new type *if* it can be converted (e.g. you might not be able to go fro ma string to an int), so the only way to do that would be to copy all data, delete the column, recreate it, convert and copy the data. Very expensive.

Comment: For easy reference the following MSDN link shows how to delete a property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633629(v=exchg.80).aspx